# could not convert string to float,' while designing the neural network model

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

I keep on getting this error when I am trying to design the neural network model for data import from csv file. Here I include my data set and the code which is giving the error.
my code is;

```
date = ""

x  = []
y  = []
x1 = []
y1 = []
x2 = []
y2 = []
data = []

np.random.seed(0)
def convertTime(s):
    tm = time.strptime(s, "%H:%M:%S")
    return datetime.datetime(date.tm_year,date.tm_mon, date.tm_mday, tm.tm_hour, tm.tm_min, tm.tm_sec)
data = np.genfromtxt('data2.csv',dtype= str,delimiter = ',')
row_num = 0
for row in data:
    if(row_num == 0):
        date = time.strptime(row[0], "Date:-%Y/%m/%d")
    elif(row_num > 1): #Data starts here
      if(row[0] != ''):
        x.append(convertTime(row[0]))
      if(row[1] != ''):
        y.append(int(row[1]))
      if(row[2] != ''):
        x1.append(convertTime(row[2]))
      if(row[3] != ''):
        y1.append(int(row[3]))
      if(row[4] != ''):
        x2.append(convertTime(row[4]))
      if(row[5] != ''):
        y2.append(int(row[5]))
    row_num = row_num + 1
print(data)
X = data[:, 0:]
Y = data[:, 1]
print(X)
print(Y)
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y)
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(X_train)
```

The error is , could not convert string to float: '0:23:40'

My data set is ,

```
Date:-2018/06/08                    
x data  y data  x1 data y1 data x2 data y2 data
0:06:15 141     0:08:00    131  0:06:45  136
0:09:25 95      0:08:15    117  0:09:30  95
0:11:00 149     0:08:30    109  0:11:30  139
0:13:50 85      0:08:45    103  0:13:30  95
0:16:25 135     0:09:00    97   0:15:25  105
0:19:00 63         -        -   0:18:00  97
0:20:00 111        -        -   0:19:30  100
0:22:05 115        -        -   0:22:15  115
0:23:40 287        -        -       -     -
```

Can you all help me to solve this problem?

Comment: This error simply suggests that your convert time is not working for some values and they are being passed as string to StandardScaler, which dont accept strings.

Comment: yes, but I need to add all the data to design my neural network. So can u suggest me some option to avoid this error? @VivekKumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an improved version of your code, properly converts your data and runs no problem  ;)

```
import numpy as np


def time_to_float(t):
    """ convert "hh:mm:ss" to float (0, 1) only of the correct format """
    if t == '-':
        return None
    a = [int(i) for i in t.split(":")]
    if len(a) == 3:
        return round((a[0] + a[1] / 60 + a[2] / 3600) / 24, 5)
    else:
        return t


def pick_column(data_, n, start=2):
    """ pick all the n'th column data starting from "start" """
    return [time_to_float(data_[i][n]) for i in range(start, len(data_))]


# read data
data = np.genfromtxt('data2.csv', dtype=str, delimiter=',')

# split data
data = [i.split() for i in data]


x = pick_column(data, 0)
y = pick_column(data, 1)
x1 = pick_column(data, 2)
y1 = pick_column(data, 3)
x2 = pick_column(data, 4)
y2 = pick_column(data, 5)


print(x)
print(y)
print(x1)
print(y1)
print(x2)
print(y2)
```

Output

```
[0.00434, 0.00654, 0.00764, 0.00961, 0.0114, 0.01319, 0.01389, 0.01534, 0.01644]
['141', '95', '149', '85', '135', '63', '111', '115', '287']
[0.00556, 0.00573, 0.0059, 0.00608, 0.00625, None, None, None, None]
['131', '117', '109', '103', '97', None, None, None, None]
[0.00469, 0.0066, 0.00799, 0.00937, 0.01071, 0.0125, 0.01354, 0.01545, None]
['136', '95', '139', '95', '105', '97', '100', '115', None]
```

Comment: I tried it . But still same error is showing . Can you tell me where exactly I should have to include this code into my code?  @Omar Cusma Fait

Comment: I tried this edit of my code then the one error is coming 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'split' . Can you tell me why this error is coming? @Omar Cusma Fait

Comment: I run Numpy 1.15.0 and this error doesn't occur to me and shouldn't occur to you as well, split converts <class 'numpy.str_'> in <class 'list'> properly on my side :/

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much for helping me. @Omar Cusma Fait

Comment: I need to put these values as X in one axis to design a neural network to predict values in dataset with time. I tried it but I couldn't do it. Can you help me to solve this problem? @Omar Cusma Fait

Comment: ok, can you  be more specific about what stuck you please? :)